# Button text disappears if button background is set to transparent

Tags: android

I have tried every permutation of setting the background of the button. The text just becomes invisible. Is there a work around?

> android:background="@color/transparent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background to transparent but keep the material button animations.

```
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

*Animation when the button is clicked:*

[image]

*Material Button:*

[image]